# insertRule not working with keyframes

Tags: javascript, css

If I use CSS without keyframes, insertRule works and everything is perfect. But if I use a CSS that contains a keyframe, I'll get the error:

> Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the
>   rule ...

**This works:**

```
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
css.insertRule(`
div {
  width: 100%;  
  animation: move 2s;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.65s;
}
`, css.cssRules.length);
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
css.insertRule(`
div {
  width: 100%;  
  animation: move 2s;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.65s;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
`, css.cssRules.length);
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posted code tries to insert two rules with a single call to `insertRule`.

Using two calls to insert a rule each

```js
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
css.insertRule(`
div {
  width: 100%;  
  animation: move 2s;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.65s;
}
`, css.cssRules.length);
css.insertRule(`
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
`, css.cssRules.length);
```

```css
div { height: 3em;}
```

```html
<div> DIV element</div>
```

works without throwing an error. Generating a syntax error if the rule parameter of `insertRule` contains more than one rule is documented on MDN in listed  [Restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule#Restrictions).